# Problem About defining Grobner Basis

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

I'm studying Commutative Algebra, and the course has a final part about Algebraic Geometry and Grobner Basis.

So, if $K$ is a field, and we have $x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}$ variables, and $I \subset K[x_{1}, \dots, x_{n}$], I understand that since $K$ is surely noetherian, by the Hilbert basis theorem $I$ is also finitely generated. If we have a certain order on monomials, we define a Grobner base for $I$ as a set of polynomials in $I$ whose leading terms (maximum grade, and among those is the biggest in the monomials order cited earlier) generate the ideal of leading terms of polynomials in $I$. Now, I don't understand these two things stated in the course:

- A Grobner base is surely a set of generators for $I$. Why?
- Every ideal surely has a Grobner base. Why?

I think I'm missing something trivial here about these sets. Could you help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, I only have the course's notes available as of now. Most of the course covered the first parts of Atiyah-Mcdonald, but the book doesn't cover these topics (to my knowledge). Could you suggest me some books that cover it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I checked out the book and I think it's the one the professor was using. Thank you so much!